# TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_11__.auth is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am trying to implement a web application using expo, react native, and firebase. I have two classes App.js and Register.js.
In App.js I initialize app and Register screen as this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
const firebaseConfig = ... 
if(firebase.apps === 0){
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
import RegisterScreen from './components/auth/Register'
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Screen name ="Register" component = {RegisterScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
      
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

In Register.js I use firebase as this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export class Register extends Component {
    constructor(props) { ... }
    
onSignUp() {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          // Signed in 
          var user = userCredential.user;
          // ...
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          // ..
        });
    }


render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button
                    onPress={() => this.onSignUp()}
                    title="Sign Up"
                />
            </View>
        )
```

I get this error : TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_11__.auth is not a function.
I tried replacing:`firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` and `import * as firebase from 'firebase'`;
with:

```
firebase.default.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) 
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import  firebase from 'firebase'
firebase.default.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

which leads to different errors like: 
Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
How can I solve this?